# Chrome exhibiting strange scrolling behavior after appending divs onto the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, append

I have a webpage that loads comments from a MySQL table, by appending "comment" divs one at a time into a collective "comments" parent div. However, this has caused some problems with scrolling in Google Chrome. I've tested this behavior in Firefox and it works fine there.

If I refresh the page anywhere above where the bottom of the page would be without any comment divs, the refresh works just fine and the scroll bar is where it should be.

However, if I refresh the page after scrolling beyond the first appended comment div, the page sets the vertical scroll position to where it would be if the comment divs weren't appended at all. I can't scroll down with the mouse wheel, as if Chrome thinks the divs were never appended, even though they are clearly there and the scrollbar shows them to be there.

If I scroll up one tick of my scroll wheel from there, the page scrolls "up" to where the scroll bar would be after scrolling up one tick from the actual bottom of the page, with all of the comment divs appended. It's like the scroll bar is in two places at once, the "bottom of the page" if the comments weren't appended and the actual bottom of the page with the comments appended. Very confusing.

Scrolling by clicking and dragging on the scrollbar works just fine. Likewise, scrolling "up" and then scrolling either up or down from there works too. I just can't scroll downward without scrolling "upward" first or starting the page refresh at a point other than one below where the bottom of the page would be without the comments appended.

I'm not entirely sure what's going on or how to fix it, and the only other mention of this I've seen on the internet doesn't have an explanation or a solution. Would anyone be familiar with what's happening, why it's happening, and how to prevent it?

Comment: The only other mention of this problem I've seen anywhere on the internet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920343/chrome-not-scrolling-when-document-height-updates

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.

Comment: I had a bit different but similar problem where Chrome didn't detect any mousewheel events in the upper half of my browser window after inserting divs. Strangely this bug was solved by simply attaching an event listener to the `div`. Seems like a dirty version to me but I haven't found any other solution yet.